# c++ Problems with destructing objects after iteration

Tags: c++, class, pointers, for-loop, memory-management

I wrote this little test program, the problem is that the program terminates and crashes after the for loop. Can someone explain whats the cause?

**What I want to accomplish**

1. create pointer for Animal objects
2. Allocate memory for 26 Animal objects
3. Set the name for each Animal object to alphabet order a-z
4. Display the name for each Animal object
5. delete all the Allocated memory by calling the destructor
6. exit main

**Source**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal {
private:
    string name;
public:
    Animal() {
        cout << "Animal created." << endl;
    }
    ~Animal() {
        cout << "Animal destructor" << endl;
    }

    void setName(string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }
    void speak() {
        cout << "My name is: " << name << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    int numberAnimals = 26;

    Animal *pAnimal = new Animal[numberAnimals];

    char test = 97; // a


    cout << "========================================================" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberAnimals; i++, test++) {

        string name(1, test);

        pAnimal[i].setName(name);
        pAnimal[i].speak();

    }

    cout << "========================================================" << endl;

    delete[] pAnimal;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your boundaries. If you'd started with a more moderate amount than 26 (like one or two) you would probably have noticed more animal chatter than expected.

Comment: And feel free to write `'a'` instead of `97`. There's no point in memorising unportable character encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numberAnimals; i++, test++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberAnimals; i++, test++)
```

You are accessing outside of bounds which leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Array elements are numbered from 0 to length-1, being 0 the first and length -1 the last; In C++, the first element in an array is always numbered with a zero (not a one) and the last element is length-1 (not length)

modify your below code

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numberAnimals; i++, test++) {

        string name(1, test);

        pAnimal[i].setName(name);
        pAnimal[i].speak();

    }
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberAnimals; i++, test++) {

        string name(1, test);

        pAnimal[i].setName(name);
        pAnimal[i].speak();

    }
```